# Case expression for null value in where clause

Tags: sql-server, case

I have a SQL procedure with two parameters `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` and SQL query inside.

For example

```
select *
from Produc p
where p.ProductType = 1 
and (ProductCategory = 5 or ProductCatalogId = 3)
or (p.StartDate between @DateFrom and @DateTo)
```

But I want a last or only when parameters `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` are not null.

Comment: what do you mean by *I want a last*?

Comment: So add `or (@DateFrom is null and @DateTo is null )`?

Comment: So when `@DateFrom` is null you don't want to apply any lower date limit and when  `@DateTo` is null you want to apply no upper date limit? Can `StartDate` be null?

Comment: Be careful with mixing `AND and `OR` by the way, you may be lacking parentheses.  You have `(p.ProductType = 1 and (ProductCategory = 5 or ProductCatalogId =3)) or (p.StartDate between @DateFrom and @DateTo)`. (I've added parentheses for clarity.

Comment: I am voting to close this topic since it is impossible to understand OPs intend neither from code nor from explaination

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select *
from Product p
where (
  p.ProductType = 1
  and (ProductCategory = 5 or ProductCatalogId =3)
)
or (
  @DateFrom is not null and @DateTo is not null
  and p.StartDate between @DateFrom and @DateTo
)
```

Although I'm wondering if thats the logic you are looking for, maybe the following is what you actually want.

```
select *
from Product p
where p.ProductType = 1
and (ProductCategory = 5 or ProductCatalogId =3)
and (
  @DateFrom is null
  or @DateTo is null
  or p.StartDate between @DateFrom and @DateTo
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the parameters to be optional. So when a parameter is null you want to ignore it and don't apply its date range limit.

A typical way for optional parameters:

```
p.StartDate between coalesce(@DateFrom, p.StartDate) and coalesce(@DateTo, p.StartDate)
```

Another, longer, but more straight-forward way:

```
(p.StartDate >= @DateFrom or @DateFrom is null)
and
(p.StartDate <= @DateTo or @DateTo is null)
```